Telegram bot that monitors and notifies any recovery attempts on Safe(Wallet)
I am writing a telegram bot in Node.js to monitor if anybody tries to use the account recovery feature of my Safe(wallet) multi-sig account.
Currently you have go into the dashboard to see if anybody is trying recover their account, which is inconvenient.
I am struggling to find any resources that can help me resolve this, any help will be appreciated.
API: https://safe.global/

As a Safe{Wallet} user, you are probably using the Safe{RecoveryHub}. It integrates both partners (Sygnum and Coincover) and a non-custodial way to recover your account.
To get notified with attempts using the partners, you will probably have to integrate with their API in some way. I will direct you towards them for more information on that.
If on the other hand you are using self-custodial methods for recovery, you can use Solidity logs to listen for events in Candide contracts, which are used by Safe under the hood. An API would listen to the events emitted by this contract and then react based on it.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
